# Magic's return value: JPEG image data in case of HEIC image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, imread, heic

Doubt 1: For HEIC images, the return value provided by Magic is JPEG. Can someone help me with the explanation? 
Doubt 2: Why is cv2.imread reading the images when in the supported file formats .HEIC is not present? Also, if there's support for cv2.imread, why is there no support for cv2.imwrite?

```
import cv2
import os
from pathlib import Path
import magic

path_of_directory = str(Path(os.getcwd()).parent) + '/images'

images = os.listdir(path_of_directory)

for image in images:
    try:
        path = str(Path(os.getcwd()).parent) + '/images/' + image
        write_path = str(Path(os.getcwd()).parent) + '/image_write/' + image
        print("image is {}".format(image))
        image_mat = cv2.imread(path)
        print("shape: {}".format(image_mat.shape))
        mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
        mime_type = mime.from_file(path)
        print("mime_type: {}".format(mime_type))
        cv2.imwrite(write_path, image_mat)
        return_value = cv2.haveImageReader(path)
        print("opencv will read the image: {}".format(return_value))

    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception occurred: {}".format(e))
```

[image]

Comment: The `magic` module (2003) appears to me to pre-date HEIC (2013) by 10 years.